# Write CSV from dictionary with specific column assignments

Tags: python, export-to-csv, defaultdict

I have a list that I could use some help writing to a csv file.

In one column - I need the category. This is the field in single quotes right before the colon. After that comes each value within the immediate set of brackets - each in it's own column:

Below is a snapshot of the print out of the list itself...

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
    'Analyzers/Blood': ['Analyzers, Laboratory, Hematology, Coagulation', 'Analyzers, Laboratory, Hematology, Coagulation, Semiautomated', 'Flowmeters, Blood, Ultrasonic'],
    'LCD Display': ['Auxiliary Displays, Touchscreen'], 
    'Electronic Endoflator': ['Balances, Electronic', 'Carts, Storage/Transport, Electromechanical/Electronic Instrument/Equipment', 'Thermometer, Electronic, Traceable']
})
```

Format example:

```
Analyzers/Blood | Analyzers | Laboratory | Hematology...(through Ultrasonic)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `for key, values in yourDict.items():` will get the keys and values. Insert the key at the front of the values and then write it with `csvwriter`.

Comment: `for k,v in d.items(): print(" | ".join([k] + [x for s in v for x in s.split(", ")]))`; where `d` is your dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated** I missed your lists could have multiple entries.

Try this:

```
dict_ = {
    'Analyzers/Blood': ['Analyzers, Laboratory, Hematology, Coagulation', 'Analyzers, Laboratory, Hematology, Coagulation, Semiautomated', 'Flowmeters, Blood, Ultrasonic'],
    'LCD Display': ['Auxiliary Displays, Touchscreen'], 
    'Electronic Endoflator': ['Balances, Electronic', 'Carts, Storage/Transport, Electromechanical/Electronic Instrument/Equipment', 'Thermometer, Electronic, Traceable']
}

with open("output.csv","w") as f:
    for k,v in dict_.items(): #py2 iteritems()
        items = [item.strip() for subv in v for item in subv.split(",")]
        f.write('|'.join([k]+list(set(items))))
        f.write('\n')
```

Output:

```
Analyzers/Blood|Blood|Ultrasonic|Coagulation|Flowmeters|Laboratory|Hematology|Analyzers|Semiautomated
LCD Display|Auxiliary Displays|Touchscreen
Electronic Endoflator|Storage/Transport|Traceable|Thermometer|Balances|Electromechanical/Electronic Instrument/Equipment|Carts|Electronic
```

Comment: What is the "w" next to the csv location? Haven't seen that before and it's returning a syntax error...